# Mobile Center CI recursive build when using git submodules

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I got a `c#` based `Xamarin.Forms` project that contains a "git submodule" as a dependency. The submodule is actually another dotnet solution with many projects, however my app only relies on one of them.

The Mobile center CI crushes while building. It seems that regardless of my entry point project references the mobile center recursively builds every single unrelated project that got cloned as a side effect. How can I tell the CI to only build the target project and its references.

What I would expect to happen is for the CI to only build my Xamarin.Forms project and its dependencies and not everything.

What am I missing?

> **note**. There is no reference link whatsoever from my entry point csproj to the one that crushes the mobile centers CI build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear that. This might be a bug in Mobile Center. In order to provide confidential information on this issue I recommend opening a conversation in the support system (the blue chat button in the lower right corner) of the Mobile Center portal. This way we can direct it at the right engineering team.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. As a matter of fact I have opened the chat before posting my question but I thought it could be something I could do on my side to stop the propagation.